# Azure "get support request" API

Tags: azure

I want to get the support requests that were added in the Azure portal under 'Help+Support' section by making an API call. I checked the REST API documentation but could not find one. Is there a REST API to get the support requests added in Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

It is not available yet, leave your feedback on this existing post here -https://feedback.azure.com/forums/266794-support-feedback/suggestions/16723438-automated-support-ticket-management  for the Azure owners to review and consider this request for the future release.

Answer (score 0):

This is now available, please take a look at the Documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/support/supporttickets/create